# Returning back to program after clicking an option in the menu

Tags: android, menu

I have the following menu option, which just *Mute/Unmute*, *Exit*, and *show an about page*.

The third case will load a picture. How do I return to my program after I click the back button after I have clicked the third case?

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.mute:
        if(toggle) {
            mMediaPlayer.setVolume(0,0f);
            Toast.makeText(SingoActivity.this, "Mute ON",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            toggle=!toggle;
        } else {
            mMediaPlayer.setVolume(1,0f);
            Toast.makeText(SingoActivity.this, "MUTE OFF",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            toggle=!toggle;
        }
        return true;

    case R.id.exit:             
        finish(); 
        System.exit(0);                 
        return true;                

    case R.id.about:
        setContentView(R.layout.help);                  
        return true;

    default:   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason for not having the help picture in a custom dialog or its own activity?

With the current implementation you would have to override onKeyDown and intercept the back button click event. If the current layout is R.layout.help, you would have to load the old layout.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        if(current layout is R.layout.help) {
            setContentView(R.layout.oldlayout);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

I would rather have used a custom dialog, a seperate activity or a FrameLayout to achieve what I think you want to achieve.

Comment: dialog = new Dialog(this);  
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.help); 

 Sorry for being a noob, my self learn skill is really limited. Would the dialog box this way? 

I try and compile, no error but when i click the help on the menu, no dialo "pop" up.

Answer (score 0):

```
dialog = new Dialog(this); 
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.help);
```

Sorry for being a noob, my self learn skill is really limited. Would the dialog box this way?

I try and compile, no error but when i click the help on the menu, no dialo "pop" up.

Comment: You need to call `dialog.show()` to make it visible. Check the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) for help with dialogs ;)